# How long will my air-layered lemon tree take to produce fruit?

Tags: fruit-trees, propagation, air-layer

I air layered a branch which is at least 1 year old (between 1-2 years) from a lemon tree which is very mature, over 15 years old and fruits profusely.

It developed a decent root system (not heaps of roots but also not too few) and I’ve just now planted it into a large pot.

How long will this likely take to produce fruit? (I did 3 individual air layers). The size of these plants are between 50 and 80 cm, and about 1/2 to 3/4 inches in diameter.